# How to download CSV from a nested object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object, javascript-objects

I want to iterate over an object in Javascript and create a CSV file from its internal objects.

```
const list = {
    "right": {
        "label": "Right",
        "items": ["Jack", "Dough"]
    },
    "wrong": {
        "label": "Wrong",
        "items": ["Rain", "Over"]
    },
    "nope": {
        "label": "Nope",
        "items": ["No", "Way"]
    }
};
const downLoadCsv = (list) => {
    let csvContent = '';
    Object.keys(statusM).forEach((obj) => {
      console.log(obj);
      //do something like obj.items and iterate over internal object - items
      //but typeof obj is string here
    });
    const anchorEle = document.createElement('a');
    anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`;
    anchorEle.target = '_blank';
    anchorEle.download = `${key}.csv`;
    anchorEle.click();
  };
```

I tried to iterate over `obj` but I found that the `typeof obj` is string. I was rather expecting an object like as follows:-

```
    {
        "label": "Right",
        "items": ["Jack", "Dough"]
    },
```

I'm expecting an output like this:-

```
  Jack, Right
  Dough, Right
  Rain, Wrong
  Over, Wrong
  No, Nope
  Way, Nope
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: here, I am not getting such output as you got. Can you please check it once again on your browser ?

Comment: Yes, you won't get this output. You'll get 'right', 'wrong', 'nope' as output. I have mentioned an expecting output in the post which I'm unable to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- so, you need to conver entire object to the next structure:

```
[
 ['Jack', 'Right'],
 ['Dough', 'Right'],
]
```

- it accomplished via this: `Object.values(list).map(i => i.items.map(j => [j, i.label])).flat()`
- after that i added extra method `toCsv` for formatting - to allow break line

```js
const list = {
    "right": {
        "label": "Right",
        "items": ["Jack", "Dough"]
    },
    "wrong": {
        "label": "Wrong",
        "items": ["Rain", "Over"]
    },
    "nope": {
        "label": "Nope",
        "items": ["No", "Way"]
    }
};

const downLoadCsv = (list) => {
    let csvContent = toCsv(Object.values(list).map(i => i.items.map(j => [j, i.label])).flat());

    const anchorEle = document.createElement('a');
    anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`;
    anchorEle.target = '_blank';
    anchorEle.download = `test.csv`;
    anchorEle.click();
  };
  
  function toCsv(arr){
    return arr.reduce(function(csvString, row){
        csvString += row.join(',') ;
    csvString += "\r\n";  //";";//"\n";
        return csvString;
    }, '');
}

downLoadCsv(list)
```

Comment: demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/shuts13/jk2u74y6/1/

Answer (score 0):

here, you need to put values instead of key but here, I have hide unrelated cuz I am unknown about that code.

```js
const list = {
    "right": {
        "label": "Right",
        "items": ["Jack", "Dough"]
    },
    "wrong": {
        "label": "Wrong",
        "items": ["Rain", "Over"]
    },
    "nope": {
        "label": "Nope",
        "items": ["No", "Way"]
    }
};
const downLoadCsv = (list) => {
    let csvContent = '';
    Object.values(list).forEach((obj) => {
      console.log(obj);
      //do something like obj.items and iterate over internal object - items
      //but typeof obj is string here
    });
    /*
    const anchorEle = document.createElement('a');
    anchorEle.href = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${encodeURI(csvContent)}`;
    anchorEle.target = '_blank';
    anchorEle.download = `${key}.csv`;
    anchorEle.click();
    */
  };
  
  downLoadCsv(list)
```